# Handling Image For Edit Mode in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular4-forms

I need to figure out how can i patch image for edit mode in Angular using reactive forms. The backend requires the image, so i need to figure out how to patch it.
I've read that you can't patch in in the input type="file". It doesn't support it? So may i ask what's the idea behind this? since it is required by the backend. It comes with other input fields so i need to patch the image because the user might not want to change the image but other input fields. Please see my code below. As you can see i'm displaying the image in the HTML and I'm not patching it in the TS because input type="file" can seem to read it. Thank you.

> HTML

```
<label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Featured Image</label>
<img class="mb-2" [src]="getUrl(tour.images[0].image)" height="200px" width="350px">
<input type="file" (change)="onSelectFeaturedImage($event)" class="form-control"
formControlName="featured_image">

<label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Travel Dates</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">From
<input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="travel_date_from">
```

> TS

```
patchValues() {
    this.tourForm.patchValue({
      travel_date_from: this.tour.date_from
    });
    this.setAsTouched(this.tourForm);
  }
```

Comment: please clarify your question, it's confusing.

Comment: @FussinHussin. Im sorry please read it throughly. Thats the best explanation ive got.

Answer (score 0):

make the `[src]` binding the value for the image input.

```
//featured_image.value
[src]="//value for image url"
```

Comment: yes, it was unclear you were doing that. could you post a working example on stackblitz.com ?

Comment: Sorry i cant do it in stackblitz since the image come from a backend. What i mean is can you patch the image in the input type =“file”? Since the image is required

Comment: if the user uploads the image, than you can store it in the browser, and retrieve it for the form

Comment: Yeah thats what i mean. But the problem relies when the user doesnt want to change the image. But instead changes other input fields. How can i achieve it since the image is required?

Comment: store the image in the browser, when the user goes to edit mode, add the image from the browser to the form. Or you can just store it in a variable in your class, and interpolate it to the template

Comment: Thats what i did. but how would i make the input type=file since it is required?

Answer (score 0):

try the following solution in jquery and pure Javascript 
you will only need to retrieve byte array of the image you uploaded and it's extension 
then just give your image controle the generated src 
I hope it helps

```
var PhotoArr = [];  // array of bytes from the server
var PhotoExt = "jpg";//example
if (PhotoArr) {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(oldResume.PhotoArr);
    var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/' + PhotoExt });
    var image = $('.mb-2');
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);

    image.attr('src', imageUrl);

}
```